How to run Heroku Scheduler against a worker dyno
I have a heroku app with no web dyno, only a worker dyno.  The worker dyno is defined by a Dockerfile.
Is there any way I can use heroku scheduler (or something equivalent) to run cron jobs against this dyno?
When I run anything from the command line like "heroku run bash -a app", it doesn't work unless I specify the --type=worker flag (I assume this is b/c by default it tries to copy the web dyno which doesn't exist).
I can't figure out if it's possible to replicate this with the scheduler add on.  Without specifying the --type=worker flag, it seems the add on also fails to run any commands because there is no web dyno.
